# Apache ReWrite rule to exclude an individual file or type of file?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Can you help me with an Apache rule to exclude a particular file name or type of file?  Here are my current rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/(?:blog)/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^crossdomain\.xml$ - [L]  (Based on first response)
RewriteRule ^/(.*_css.*\.css.*) /$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*_js.*\.js.*) /$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*_swf.*\.swf.*) /$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*_img.*\.[jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|gif|GIF|bmp|BMP|png|PNG].*) /$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I am trying to exclude my Flash crossdomain.xml file from getting rewritten. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put this rule on top of yours:

```
RewriteRule ^/crossdomain\.xml$ - [L]
```

Comment: Hey Gumbo, I added the line you requested as you can see above.  But I still get redirected when I try and access the crossdomain.xml file.  Any other thoughts?